# AngularJS Response Interceptors and Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble coding this and getting it to work.  I'm not sure I did the promises right or the respones data.

It should append access_token to every request and check every response error for 401 and then try to refresh the token and then if that fails get a brand new token.

Here is the routes file, check the bottom for the relevant code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('sawebpanel.routes')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider'];

  /**
   * @name config
   * @desc Define valid application routes
   */
  function config($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      controller: 'IndexController', 
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/layout/index.html'
    }).when('/accounts/register', {
      controller: 'RegisterController', 
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/register.html'
    }).when('/accounts/login', {
      controller: 'LoginController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/login.html'
    }).when('/accounts/+:username', {
      controller: 'AccountController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/accounts/account.html'
    }).when('/accounts/+:username/settings', {
      controller: 'AccountSettingsController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/accounts/settings.html'
    }).when('/accounts/+:username/profile', {
      controller: 'AccountProfileController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/accounts/profile.html'
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope, $q, $injector, $location) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {

            config.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + $rootScope.oauth.access_token;
            return config;
        },

        'responseError': function(response) {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            params = JSON.stringify({
              refresh_token: $rootScope.oauth.refresh_token,
              client_id: $rootScope.oauth.client_id,
              client_secret: $rootScope.oauth.client_secret,
              grant_type: "password"
            });
            $injector.get("$http").jsonp('/api/v1/auth/token?' + params).then(function($refreshResponse) { // try to refresh token
              if (refreshResponse.data) {
                $rootScope.oauth = angular.fromJson($refreshResponse.data); // set oauth data

                $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(response) { 
                  deferred.resolve(response);  
                }, function(response) {
                  deferred.reject(); // no data in response
                });
              } else {
                deferred.reject();
              }
            }, function(response) {
              params = JSON.stringify({
                client_id: $rootScope.oauth.client_id,
                client_secret: $rootScope.oauth.client_secret,
                grant_type: "password"
              });
              $injector.get("$http").jsonp('/api/v1/auth/token?' + params).then(function($loginResponse) { // try for a new token
                if ($loginResponse.data) {
                  $rootScope.oauth = angular.fromJson($loginResponse.data); // set oauth data

                  $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(response) { 
                    deferred.resolve(response);  
                  }, function(response) {
                    deferred.reject();
                  });
                }, else {
                  deferred.reject(); // no data in response
                }
              }, function(response) {
                deferred.reject();
                $location.path('/accounts/login'); // give up and redirect to login
                return;
              });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
          }
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    });
  }
})();
```

I was told to put this line in for checking if the respone worked and set the token but i'm not sure if it's correct.

```
$injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(response) {
                  deferred.resolve(response);  
                }, function(response) {
                  deferred.reject();
                });
```

I need help specifically with making sure the $rootScope.oauth data structure is delcared correctly and that I'm setting the attributes right.  And that the promises are set up correct in the responeError function.  And that the jsonp() calls have the correct arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config function is global and it may conflict with interceptor request config param. So make you config function like :-

```
   angular
   .module('sawebpanel.routes').config(function(){
      //Your code...
   });
```

For interceptor make a service seprately for interceptor and push it to interceptors array..
I recently have implemented the same. I have written all the scenario in my blog, it will definitely helps you :-

http://www.codemosquitoes.com/2016/06/using-angularjs-interceptors-with-http.html

Let me know if you have any question.

Here is the tokenService implementation:-

```
   angular.module("app").service('tokenService', ["$cookies", "$injector", "$q", function ($cookies, $injector, $q) {
var services = {};

services.tokenValue = function () {
    return $cookies.get('token');
};

services.setTokenCookie = function (key, value) {
    var expireDate = new Date();
    expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
    $cookies.put(key, value, { 'expires': expireDate, path: '/' });
}

services.refreshToken = function (isAuth) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http = $injector.get('$http');
    $http.get('urlForGettingTokenApi').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve("Error");
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

return services;
}]);
```

Cheers

Comment: Well I already have the one config function.  Would I just set up my interceptors in that?  Also where do you define tokenService?

Comment: I've been reading your post, and it's been a big help.  But I have a few questions.  Do I need separate interceptors for respone and request or can't I just put responseError and request in the same function?  My other question is about storing the oauth data.  I am using $rootScope.oauth.data but I'm not sure if I am using it correctly.  Could you give me an example of how to defined/setup your tokenService or how I should set up $rootScope.oauth ?

Comment: You can set up your interceptor in same config section you already have. Also you can put responseError and request in same interceptor. 

For storing oauth data you can use $rootScope, I don't think there will be any problem.

But in responseError :-

Comment: You can set up your interceptor in same config section you already have. Also you can put responseError and request in same interceptor. 

For storing oauth data you can use $rootScope, I don't think there will be any problem.

But in responseError :- 

$injector.get("$http").jsonp('/api/v1/auth/token?' + params) after this call, in error function why are you making this call again. just reject the promise here. 

the tokenService is just a seprate service in which I have some function like getToken(), refreshToken() and so on....

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to use the `` provider without injecting it. Change your `config` function definition to inject the `` provider:

```
angular
  .module('sawebpanel.routes')
  .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider'];

  /**
   * @name config
   * @desc Define valid application routes
   */
  function config($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

  }
```

Comment: So I have 2 config functions, can I just move my interceptors into the single one?  Or how can I call 2 config functions on the module?

Comment: See my updated code example, is this what you meant?  Also am I using $rootScope correctly?  I am confused with setting up the data structure to hold the oauth data.

Comment: You can use any number of configs in a chained way or in multiple files. As for your second question it seems right